# Postgresql connection with gorm dial error cannot assign requested address

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to use the new gorm v2 implementation with Postgresql (I use Docker for the Golang app and for Postgres). I tried to do it as shown in the [gorm documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/connecting_to_the_database.html#PostgreSQL).

That gave me the following error:

> web_1  | 2020/09/19 19:25:57 /go/src/caiqueservice/main.go:36 failed
> to connect to `host=/tmp user=admin database=caique`: dial error (dial
> unix /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432: connect: no such file or directory)

So since the documentation didn't specify `host`, but the error message set that to */tmp* I set that value.

```
dsn := fmt.Sprintf("host=%v user=%v password=%v dbname=%v port=%v sslmode=disable",
    os.Getenv("DB_HOST"),
    os.Getenv("DB_USERNAME"),
    os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
    os.Getenv("DB_DATABASE"),
    os.Getenv("DB_PORT"),
)
db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
```

.env

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=caique
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Doing so gives me the following error message:

> web_1  | 2020/09/19 19:36:47 /go/src/caiqueservice/main.go:36 failed
> to connect to `host=localhost user=admin database=caique`: dial error
> (dial tcp [::1]:5432: connect: cannot assign requested address)

The postgres db is reachable by pgadmin.
I don't know what to do next and help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: is pgadmin connecting to localhost:5432?

Comment: Yes, it is @elemetrics

Comment: for dev purpose, you can also use `172.17.0.1` as hostname (container -> host machine)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside a container, `localhost` refers to the container itself, not to the host machine. If you are using docker-compose, you should be able to connect to the postgres container (from the app container) using the postgres container name as the host name. If you are running both containers separately, you will need to connect them to the same docker network or [link](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) them.